# Adapting the X-axis according to Day Light Saving change using MS Chart

Tags: c#, timezone, mschart, dst

I am using MS Chart to show time series data on line chart. The data points have time stamp and values. I am using DateTimeOffset to encode the Time zone as well as Day light saving with respect to UTC time.

```
chart = new Chart();
var chartArea = new ChartArea("Name");
chartArea.Position = new ElementPosition(xChartArea, yChartArea, wChartArea, hChartArea);
chartArea.InnerPlotPosition = new ElementPosition(xInnerPlot, yInnerPlot, wInnerPlot, hInnerPlot);

var series = new Series(seriesName)
                {
                    ChartArea = ChartAreaName,
                    XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTimeOffset,
                }
foreach(var record in records)
{
  chart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(record.dateTimeOffset.DateTime.ToOADate(), record.value);
}
```

Due to change in Day light saving (DST) the chart would like this[image]

which shows a redundant line at value 1 due to DST change.
If UTCDateTime instead of DateTime while inserting into series like this

```
foreach(var record in records)
{
  chart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(record.dateTimeOffset.UtcDateTime.ToOADate(), record.value);
}
```

I loose the local time and DST on X-axis:
[image]

I need to show the curve as the second chart but the X-axis should show the jump in DST, how can I achieve this?
How can I pass the local or DST to MS Chart?

Comment: The axis itself would have to be altered, because local time is non-linear at the discontinuities of DST transitions.  I'm not sure if MS Chart can do that or not.